# Updating regex to ignore new line and quote at end of line

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to convert the following String to an array of String elements using regex :

```
"a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7"
```

Here is the regex I use :

```
",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

Adding this into Java code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestRegex {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        final String line = "a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7";
        final String[] row = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

        Arrays.stream(row).forEach(element -> System.out.println("element : "+element));

    }
}
```

prints :

```
element : a
element : b
element : c
element : 
element : 1
element : 19
element : d
element : U
element : 1
element : 0
element : 
element : 0
element : 7
```

So far, so good. If I then add `"` and `\n` to the line variable : "a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7"\n" the elements are not parsed correctly.

Updating the code with the new regex :

```
public class TestRegex {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        final String line = "a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7\"\n";
        final String[] row = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

        Arrays.stream(row).forEach(element -> System.out.println("element : "+element));

    }
}
```

prints :

```
element : a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7"
```

I could modify the String to replace all instances of " and \n but I'm attempting to use regex. Can the regex be updated to ignore \n and " a the end of String "a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7" ?

So that following should be printed :

```
element : a
element : b
element : c
element : 
element : 1
element : 19
element : d
element : U
element : 1
element : 0
element : 
element : 0
element : 7
```

Comment: Why is `line.split(",")` insufficient for your needs? CSV parsers exist...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split using:

```
[,\"\n]
```

**Code:**

```sh
jshell> String line = "a,b,c,,1,19,d,U,1,0,,0,7\"\n";
jshell> line.split("[,\"\n]");
$102 ==> String[13] { "a", "b", "c", "", "1", "19", "d", "U", "1", "0", "", "0", "7" }
```

Here `[,\"\n]` is a character class that matches `,` or `"` or `\n` for splitting.

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/cmPaEt)